# Retrieve the value of the select option in a View

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails-4

I have the following in my view:

```
<%= select_tag(:option_id, options_for_select([
                     ['Students', 1],
                     ['Teachers', 2],
                     ])) %>
```

How do I retrieve the selected value in my View itself? I want to dynamically change the value of a `<%= link_to %>` based on it.

Here's my partial coffee script:

```
jQuery ->
  $('#import_type').change ->
```

How do I now change the value of a `<%= link_to %>`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do something like:

```
jQuery ->
  $('#import_type').change ->
    if $('#import_type').val() == '1'
      $('#link_to_id').attr("attribute", "value")
```

Make sure you replace `link_to_id` with the actual id.